# Installing programs/saving files on persitence or not

Tags: microsoft-office, persistence

I wanted to install Office 2010 and save files that I use daily but as I am a rookie to Ubuntu and Linux in general, I don't know if it makes a difference where I save it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can Install Office 2010 by using wine as explained  here http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/04/installing-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu-has-gotten-a-lot-easier-with-wine/

after installing it completely , use it and save the files anywhere but Home is recommended  then you can either open them in Office by wine or by simply ussing libre Office.

Hope it helped you.